# Sorting in SQL on varchar column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following columns in **activities** table in a POSTGRES database:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID integer,      => unique integers
DATE bigint,              => stores epoch values     
ACTIVITY_ID varchar(10),  => stores unique character values
ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID integer  => values 1 to 5
```

There could be multiple records with same DATE values. My question is which one will be more efficient:

```
1. select * from activities order by DATE desc, ACTIVITY_ID

2. select * from activities order by DATE desc, ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID
```

First one uses bigint + varchar for sorting

Second one uses bigint + integer + integer

Comment: Try them on your data, get an explain output for both and update the question with those outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The sort is a sort is a sort.  Your query will only be efficient if you have the appropriate indexes on the two or three columns.

Lacking that, the difference that the size of the key makes is relatively minor.  There is a bit of an efficiency gain from having all the keys be the same size.  And, if the string field is hundreds of bytes long, then it will make a difference.

You should try both on your data and report back.  I wouldn't worry about the difference in performance.  There must be other more important things to think about.

Comment: And; is it functionally more logical to sort by activity_id? Sorting by internally useful ids often isn't useful to people

Comment: That depends on your use-case and requirements. Ask your users!